# Why are representations of sl($2,\mathbb C$) finite dimensional

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Trying to understand some basic representation theory I came across the following saying.

"Since the representation of $sl(2;C)$ has to be finite dimensional, there must exist an integer $n \in N_0$ with $(J_+)^{n+1}|u> = 0$, and $(J_+)^n|u> \ne  0$."

Key for this argument is that the representation is finite dimensional. However, it is not obvious to me what it has to be, and I would greatly appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Seconding what Matthew said. Just adding that in many contexts (such as applications fo quantum mechanics) the finite dimensional representations are the most interesting. They are also a natural collection of objects in pure algebra.

Comment: This is from somewhat informal course notes in a course called Group theory in physics. Thanks for the comments, I now consider the question answered.

Comment: It is just plain wrong to say that only finite dimensional representations are physically interesting. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group

Answer (score 1):

There are well-known infinite-dimensional modules for the Lie algebra $L=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$. We start with an action of $L$ on the polynomial ring $\Bbb C[X,Y]$ and pass to the subspace of homogeneous polynomials.

References:

[Infinite dimensional $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77995/infinite-dimensional-sl2-mathbbc-modules)

[Proof check - infinite-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{F})$-module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367712/proof-check-infinite-dimensional-mathfraksl2-mathbbf-module?rq=1)